# iOS unit tests crashing randomly on Jenkins with no backtrace

Tags: ios, unit-testing, jenkins

We have an iOS unit test (XCTest) suite we run on Jenkins using this command:
`xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme MyScheme -destination platform='iOS Simulator',name='iPhone 6' clean test RUN_UNIT_TESTS=YES`

Every once in a while (less than once a day) we get the suite failing with this error:

`Testing failed:
MyTest encountered an error (Test session exited(-1) without completing. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/folders/bp/z5grkxn50z1ffym24hsk17fc00007q/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest-status/Session-2015-08-14_14:28:55-cPXXXX.log)
** TEST FAILED **
...
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure`

My guess is that the app is crashing during the test run. Every once in a while I'll see the test suite crash when running the app on my machine in Xcode. I'm usually busy in the middle of trying to get my work done and don't want to investigate so I'll re-run the tests and they'll pass. When this happens on my machine I've noticed the crash happening in a background thread. It's probably some dependency we're not stubbing in our test suite that's not configured correctly under test and it's trying to make network requests.

My question is, is there a way to get a backtrace from such crashes? I looked in the log file mentioned in the error message but that file doesn't have any more information on the crash.

It might also be worth mentioning that our test suite is configured to run within the iOS simulator, if that makes a difference.

Comment: It's printed out the name of a log file for you. What's in there?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, the log file has no additional details. I ended up resolving this issue by actually taking the time to look at the backtrace carefully when this happened once on my machine. It turns out we had a unit test that wasn't stubbing our network calls which was causing the test suite to fail randomly.